# Optimising a trivial MySQL query to get rid of filesort

Tags: mysql, optimization

I've got a trivial mysql query which isn't liked by the server really:

```
SELECT zone_id, SUM(inc_sec) AS voucher_used
  FROM cdr_bill_2010_09
 WHERE cust_id = 1234 AND voucher_id = 'XXXXXX'
 GROUP BY zone_id
```

Now this should be really quick (and usually is) since there are indexes on both cust_id and voucher_id (voucher_id is chosen). However it still uses helper tables. After explaining:

```
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: cdr_bill_2010_09
         type: ref
possible_keys: cust_id,voucher_id
          key: voucher_id
      key_len: 9
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Can I do something specific to get rid of those? I'm running debian's 5.0.45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer was close to the other ones. Adding an index with both "where" key `(voucher_id)` or `(cust_id)` and the "group" key `(zone_id)` fixed the problem. Actually `zone_id` itself was sufficient to get rid of additional temporary / filesort, but adding another one was needed to use the speed up the basic query.

Answer (score 2):

just try to add another index (according to http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,57443,59562):

```
CREATE INDEX index_zi ON cdr_bill_2010_09 (zone_id,inc_sec);
```

Comment: Well... I don't see much point in indexing the columns I select. These are not used in the `where` part.

Comment: For heaven's sake, @viraptor!  The reason your query uses a temp table is to do the summing called for by group_by. indexes have more uses than just record selection.  The reference @msurovcak gave you explains how to solve your problem.  It remains true even if you don't see the point of it.

Comment: Well... no, actually it doesn't. I see the point of `zone_id` index (well - it solved my problem to add zone_id), but why would I ever include `inc_sec`? It's never used for filtering / grouping / whatever.

Comment: Hi, index I suggested says something like: if you want too know whats the value of inc_sec for given zone_id look right here! So MySQL doesn't need to build another table to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you indexing all the bytes in the voucher_id?

from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html :

> You index only a prefix of a column
>   named in the ORDER BY clause. In this
>   case, the index cannot be used to
>   fully resolve the sort order. For
>   example, if you have a CHAR(20)
>   column, but index only the first 10
>   bytes, the index cannot distinguish
>   values past the 10th byte and a
>   filesort will be needed.

I know it's not an order by clause, but maybe the same deal?

Comment: On explain `rows==1`, so it's not really needed to examine many rows. (also, only 10 rows are summed up) `voucher_id` is only 7 chars long too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating an index with both cust_id and vendor_id in it?

```
create index idx_cdr_bill_2010_09_joint on cdr_bill_2010_09(cust_id, vendor_id)
```

Comment: This did not help. Actually using the new index, I get 14 rows to look through instead of 1 (with `cust_id, voucher_id`) or 36 rows (with `voucher_id, cust_id`). Both are using temporary table and filesort.

Answer (score 0):

> CREATE INDEX IDX_CDRBILL_CUST_VOUCH_ZONE ON cdr_bill_2010_09 (cust_id,
>   voucher_id, zone_id);